# Get selected array's value in a different table cell

Tags: php, jquery

I have this array

```
$array = [
    'A1' => 'Is there a site plan and/or schematic showing location of Source, chambers, 
             tanks, distribution network including valves, pipes, consumer premises etc.?',
    'A2' => 'Are there any procedures and/or written records for the supply? (I.e for 
             checks, monitoring or maintenance, etc.)?',
     .
     .
];
```

And this table

```
    echo '  <tr>';
    echo '    <td>';

    echo '<select id="riskno1" name="riskno1">';
      foreach( $array as $let => $word ) {
        echo '<option value="' . $word . '">' . $let . '</option>'; 
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td></td>';
    echo '<td></td>';
    echo '<td></td>';
    echo '  </tr>';
```

How can I get the selected `$let` value from the dropdown menu and have it echoed/stored in another table cell AND have it shown to the user when he 
selects it?

For example the user chooses 'A1' from the dropdown menu and I want in the next cell to have the array's info displayed (Is there a site plan and/or schematic showing location of Source, chambers, tanks, distribution network including valves, pipes, consumer premises etc.?) and be stored somewhere. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "and be stored somewhere"?

Comment: For example use an <input type="hidden"> with the value 'Is there a site plan and/or schematic showing location of Source, chambers, tanks, distribution network including valves, pipes, consumer premises etc.?' stored in it if I selected A1